# npm install error 4058, can't install private module in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I can't install my private module call storage:0.1.1 when I command `npm install` in the root path.

I write package.json to install this module as:

```
"dependencies": {
  "storage": "file:modules/storage"
}
```

And I also write package.json in the private module stroage already, it's work on my linux well, on windows well before, but one day I install occur error -4058

And there are error message:

> 909 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\vincent_lin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\storage\0.1.1\package.tgz'
>   909 verbose stack     at Error (native) 
>   910 verbose cwd D:\networkteam\meta\git_meta_static_develop 
>   911 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601 
>   912 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" 
>   913 error node v4.4.2 
>   914 error npm  v2.15.0 
>   915 error path C:\Users\vincent_lin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\storage\0.1.1\package.tgz 
>   916 error code ENOENT 
>   917 error errno -4058 
>   918 error syscall scandir 
>   919 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\vincent_lin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\storage\0.1.1\package.tgz' 
>   919 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself 919 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
>   920 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

PS: I have tried to use powershell with administration and I checked the path 
`C:\Users\vincent_lin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\storage\0.1.1\package.tgz`
is correct.
And I ever update npm to latest version, it still exist error.

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you must use \ slash and not / slash.

Please provide relative path starting with a .\

Eg: `"dependencies": { "storage": "file:.\modules\storage" }`

Or provide the full path starting with the drive letter.

Comment: Thanks, I follow your suggestions to modify it, but return the same error message.

Comment: Maybe json parser will automatic transfer that for Windows? I am not sure about that. I fixed that and return failed to parse json error.